# Need to update the particular section of the UI

Tags: angular, ng-template

I have a UI where the number of select dropdowns is dynamic. So if its 5, then i will show 5 dropdowns to the user. The options in all dropdowns are the same. But if user selects a particular option i need to fetch the data from a map and show it in the same section as the dropdown.

The object inside Map which is used to render the data is a complex mix of : arrays and maps. Once the section is rendered and the user selects a different drop down , I would only want to render that section again and not the whole page. I believe track-by feature of the ng-template does that.

Is it possible to have a solution where I just have one template which is iterated over depending on the number of drop downs and it knows which drop down it belongs to. So only that section of template refreshes if the drop down value changes.

Is ng-template the best way to achieve this ? would i have to maintain some of index to know which drop down got selected ?

This stackblitz represents what i am trying to achieve

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f3qp4y

Answer (score 1):

It could be a bit easier with reactive forms rather than template-driven forms. But as you mentioned, one way would be to track the looped items with an index. One way would be to store the model values in an array and fetch them based on the index. Not sure if it's the best of solutions, but it should work:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fxotqc

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep track of your dropdown value. Here is what I suggest:

```js
dropdowns = [];

ngOnInit(){
    for (let i = 0; i < this.numOfTemplates; i++) {
      this.dropdowns.push({
        model: '',
        color: ''
      });
    }
    this.mp.set("Ford",{model : "Ford Mustang", color : "Red"});
    this.mp.set("Volvo",{model : "Volvo XC90", color : "White"});
    this.mp.set("Fiat",{model : "Foat 500", color : "Black"});
  }

refresh(val :any, dropdown){
  const setVal = this.mp.get(val.target.value);
  dropdown.model = setVal.model;
  dropdown.color = setVal.model;
}
```

And then, on the HTML side:

```html
<div *ngFor="let in of dropdowns">
<select (change)="refresh($event, in)">  
        <option [value]="car.value" *ngFor="let car of cars">{{car.value}}</option>  
</select> 
Model : {{in.model}} , Color : {{in.color}}:
</div>
```

Comment: Guys. I didn’t provide enough details as to why I asked about a ng-template solution. I just updated my question. Apologies for the confusion.